# How to convert MATLAB Coder C Code to MATLAB Original Code

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I have C Code generated from MATLAB Coder. I lost the SimuLink model that generates this code. There is any form to do the inverse process? That means, convert the previously C Code generated from MATLAB to the original MATLAB code.

Comment: Trial and error — take a guess at what the model looked like, generate C code, compare to your existing C code, guess at what you need to change to make them match.

Comment: perhaps contact MathWorks and ask them. they wrote the generator, they may have ways, or ideas how to, map the generated code back to a simulink model or matlab code.